# Media Queries Working on Mobile But Not on Browser Resize

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, response

I'm using the following code at the top of my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/960-12-15-15-fluid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/gsfest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/gsfest-tablet-portrait.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" />
    <!--<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/gsfest-smartphone-landscape.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" />-->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/gsfest-smartphone-portrait.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 320px)" />
</head>
```

The responsive CSS loads fine when browsing with a mobile device and also with the Responsive Design View in FF, but when I simply try to resize the browser in FF or Chrome it sticks with the desktop layout.

Does anyone know why? I'm using the same code that I always use and haven't had this problem in the past, unless there's something I've forgot to include

Comment: Can you share some css also? A jsfiddle would be better.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell the full story from what you've posted, but you could start by tweaking your viewport meta tag to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
```

Also, remember that the standard cascading rules still apply, so if you have a rule set in your first two stylesheets (960-12-15-15-fluid.css and gsfest.css), that would apply at different viewports if it had higher [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Good luck

Comment: thanks, just tried it but it didn't seem to work. Then after looking into it some more I realised it was loading the tablet styles fine but the browser wouldn't go as narrow as 320px on resize! And there was no stylesheet setup yet for smartphone portrait